# WPF GridView not Binding to Collection

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview, collections, binding

i've been researching on how to Bind a GridView to a ObservableCollection. All the examples do the same steps, but it doesn't work on my application.

I have even copied the example here: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-the-listview-part-1

The DisplayMemberBinding is working when declare the items in XAML so the problem must be the collection.

For XAML:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding GameCollection}" Margin="0,123,0,41">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Game Name" 
         DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding GameName}"  />
                <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Creator"  
         DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Creator}" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Publisher" 
         DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Publisher}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

For the CS

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ObservableCollection<GameData> _GameCollection =
    new ObservableCollection<GameData>();


    public MainWindow()
    {
        _GameCollection.Add(new GameData
        {
            GameName = "World Of Warcraft",
            Creator = "Blizzard",
            Publisher = "Blizzard"
        });
        _GameCollection.Add(new GameData
        {
            GameName = "Halo",
            Creator = "Bungie",
            Publisher = "Microsoft"
        });
        _GameCollection.Add(new GameData
        {
            GameName = "Gears Of War",
            Creator = "Epic",
            Publisher = "Microsoft"
        });


        InitializeComponent();
        Focus();
    }


    public ObservableCollection<GameData> GameCollection
    { get { return _GameCollection; } }
}

public class GameData
{
    public string GameName { get; set; }
    public string Creator { get; set; }
    public string Publisher { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your binding won't be finding the property on your form.  You're not specifying where to find `GameCollection`: the binding doesn't know where to look.

Add a `x:Name="someName"` to the root element of your Window, and then modify the binding to be `{Binding GameCollection, ElementName=someName}`.  That'll fix the problem with the binding.

Comment: Actually, there is a Property called `GameCollection` further down so only the ElementName part applies

Comment: Sorry!  Failure to scroll, I guess :-)  Editing!

Comment: Yes, it was the name problem, it's working perfectly now, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

actually all u need to do is make sure the datacontext is set properly

DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" put that in the tag for the window.